# Wrong ouput with kinit, kadmin, klist

Tags: ubuntu, mitkerberos

I am unable to use the kadmin command after entering the password.  list_principals, and  klist returns the output "true" without information about the ticket.

Where is the information about the ticket and the option to enter commands in the kadmin interface?

```
:~$ kadmin
Authenticating as principal norbert/admin@ubunturealm with password.
kadmin: true while initializing kadmin interface
:~$ klist
klist: true
:~$ kinit
kinit: true while getting initial credentials
:~$
```

krb5.conf

```
:/etc$ cat krb5.conf
[libdefaults]
default_realm = ubunturealm
dns_lookup_realm = true
dns_lookup_kdc = true
dns_canonicalize_hostname = true
dns_uri_lookup = true 
rdns = true 
# The following krb5.conf variables are only for MIT Kerberos.
kdc_timesync = 1
ccache_type = 4
forwardable = true
proxiable = true
clockskew = 300s
default_ccache_name = DEFCCNAME
default_client_keytab_name = DEFCKTNAME
default_keytab_name = DEFKTNAME
#default_tgs_enctypes = 
#default_tks_enctypes = 
enforce_ok_as_delagate = true
err_fmt = true
extra_addresses = true
# SPRAWDZ MULTIHOMED HOSTNAMES i VIRTUAL HOSTING ENV zanim to ustawisz
#ignore_acceptor_hostname = true
k5login_authoritative = true
k5login_directory = true
#on mac os only kcm_mach_service 
#on mac os only kcm_socket
#kdc_default_options = 0x00000010
kdc_timesync = 1
#noaddresses = true
#permitted_enctypes =
plugin_base_dir = krb5/plugins
#preferred_preauth_types = 17, 16, 14, 14
#qualify_shortname
#realm_try_domains = 
#renew_lifetime = 0
spake_preauth_groups = edwards25519
ticket_lifetime = 1d
#ustalic ile potrzeba na udp_preference_limit = 
# trzeba ogarnac to z keytabem na kliencie i na serwerze 
# zwiazek z keytabem verify_ap_req_nofail = false
allow_des3 = false
allow_rc4 = false 
allow_weak_crypto = false
canonicalize = true
client_aware_channel_bindings = true


 # The following libdefaults parameters are only for Heimdal Kerberos.
fcc-mit-ticketflags = true

 [realms]
ubunturealm = {
    kdc = serverkerberos
    admin_server = adminserverkerberos
    default_domain = ubuntuserver
#   auth_to_local =  RULE:[2:$2](^.*;root)s/^.*$/root/}
}

#ATHENA.MIT.EDU = {
#   kdc = kerberos.mit.edu
#   kdc = kerberos-1.mit.edu
#   kdc = kerberos-2.mit.edu:88
#   admin_server = kerberos.mit.edu
#   default_domain = mit.edu
#}
#ZONE.MIT.EDU = {
#   kdc = casio.mit.edu
#   kdc = seiko.mit.edu
#   admin_server = casio.mit.edu
#}
#SAIL.MIT.EDU = {
#   admin_server = kerberos.csail.mit.edu
#   default_domain = csail.mit.edu
#}
#IHTFP.ORG = {
#   kdc = kerberos.ihtfp.org
#   admin_server = kerberos.ihtfp.org
#}
#TS.ORG = {
#   kdc = kerberos.1ts.org
#   admin_server = kerberos.1ts.org
#}
#ANDREW.CMU.EDU = {
#   admin_server = kerberos.andrew.cmu.edu
#   default_domain = andrew.cmu.edu
#}
    #CS.CMU.EDU = {
    #        kdc = kerberos-1.srv.cs.cmu.edu
    #        kdc = kerberos-2.srv.cs.cmu.edu
    #        kdc = kerberos-3.srv.cs.cmu.edu
    #        admin_server = kerberos.cs.cmu.edu
    #}
#DEMENTIA.ORG = {
#   kdc = kerberos.dementix.org
#   kdc = kerberos2.dementix.org
#   admin_server = kerberos.dementix.org
#}
#stanford.edu = {
#   kdc = krb5auth1.stanford.edu
#   kdc = krb5auth2.stanford.edu
#   kdc = krb5auth3.stanford.edu
#   master_kdc = krb5auth1.stanford.edu
#   admin_server = krb5-admin.stanford.edu
#   default_domain = stanford.edu
#}
    #UTORONTO.CA = {
    #        kdc = kerberos1.utoronto.ca
    #        kdc = kerberos2.utoronto.ca
    #        kdc = kerberos3.utoronto.ca
    #        admin_server = kerberos1.utoronto.ca
    #        default_domain = utoronto.ca
#}

[domain_realm]
#.mit.edu = ATHENA.MIT.EDU
#mit.edu = ATHENA.MIT.EDU
#.media.mit.edu = MEDIA-LAB.MIT.EDU
#media.mit.edu = MEDIA-LAB.MIT.EDU
#.csail.mit.edu = CSAIL.MIT.EDU
#csail.mit.edu = CSAIL.MIT.EDU
#.whoi.edu = ATHENA.MIT.EDU
#whoi.edu = ATHENA.MIT.EDU
#.stanford.edu = stanford.edu
#.slac.stanford.edu = SLAC.STANFORD.EDU
#.toronto.edu = UTORONTO.CA
#.utoronto.ca = UTORONTO.CA
```

Systemctl

```
● krb5-kdc.service - Kerberos 5 Key Distribution Center
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/krb5-kdc.service; enabled; preset: ena>
 Active: active (running) since Sun 2024-03-10 09:45:33 UTC; 6min ago
  Main PID: 824 (krb5kdc)
  Tasks: 1 (limit: 5673)
 Memory: 1.3M
    CPU: 35ms
 CGroup: /system.slice/krb5-kdc.service
         └─824 /usr/sbin/krb5kdc -P /var/run/krb5-kdc.pid

 Mar 10 09:45:33 ubuntuserver krb5kdc[754]: Setting pktinfo on socket ::.88
 Mar 10 09:45:33 ubuntuserver krb5kdc[754]: Setting up TCP socket for address 0.>
 Mar 10 09:45:33 ubuntuserver krb5kdc[754]: Setting up TCP socket for address ::>
 Mar 10 09:45:33 ubuntuserver krb5kdc[754]: setsockopt(14,IPV6_V6ONLY,1) worked
 Mar 10 09:45:33 ubuntuserver krb5kdc[754]: set up 6 sockets
 Mar 10 09:45:33 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: krb5-kdc.service: Can't open PID file >
Mar 10 09:45:33 ubuntuserver krb5kdc[824]: commencing operation
Mar 10 09:45:33 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Started krb5-kdc.service - Kerberos 5 >
Mar 10 09:47:07 ubuntuserver krb5kdc[824]: AS_REQ (8 etypes {aes256-cts-hmac-sh>
Mar 10 09:47:19 ubuntuserver krb5kdc[824]: AS_REQ (8 etypes {aes256-cts-hmac-sh>
```

Syslog

```
  2024-03-10T10:14:24.376053+00:00 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Started krb5-kdc.service - Kerberos 5 Key Distribution Center.
  2024-03-10T10:14:59.038335+00:00 ubuntuserver krb5kdc[5630]: AS_REQ (8 etypes {aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96(18), aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96(17), aes256-cts-hmac-sha384-192(20), aes128-cts-hmac-sha256-128(19), DEPRECATED:des3-cbc-sha1(16), DEPRECATED:arcfour-hmac(23), camellia128-cts-cmac(25), camellia256-cts-cmac(26)}) 192.168.1.16: NEEDED_PREAUTH: root/admin@ubunturealm for kadmin/admin@ubunturealm, true
  2024-03-10T10:15:00.889791+00:00 ubuntuserver krb5kdc[5630]: preauth (encrypted_timestamp) verify failure: true
  2024-03-10T10:15:00.889855+00:00 ubuntuserver krb5kdc[5630]:  AS_REQ (8 etypes {aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96(18), aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96(17), aes256-cts-hmac-sha384-192(20), aes128-cts-hmac-sha256-128(19), DEPRECATED:des3-cbc-sha1(16), DEPRECATED:arcfour-hmac(23), camellia128-cts-cmac(25), camellia256-cts-cmac(26)}) 192.168.1.16: PREAUTH_FAILED: root/admin@ubunturealm for kadmin/admin@ubunturealm, true
```

[image: auth.log]

Comment: I would check for aliases or if someone has created a command or script which is references earlier in your path.

Comment: " Or if someone " what you mean. Btw. thanks for responding, you giving me clue to resolve that. But when i comment all my conf parameters system of kerberos dont work.

Comment: is your server up to date in terms of time synchronization ? (correct time and/or synchronized against a time server). Also, what gives you "kadmin -p norbert/admin@ubunturealm" ? same error ?

Comment: Yeah @olivierg the same error, and i use ntp to sybnchronize time server. I updated post with auth.log, please check, maybe something come to you.

Comment: Please use copy-paste and avoid posting screenshots of text when posting console output / settings. Format that text  as "`code`" using [Markdown](https://serverfault.com/editing-help) and/or the formatting options in the edit menu to properly type-set your posts. That improves readability, attracts better answers and allows indexing by search engines, which may help people with similar questions. And that will allow people willing to answer your question to also copy-and-paste your commands/settings/error messages into their answer.